# side by side buttons with jquery-mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jquery-mobile, and I have these two buttons:

```
<p id="propart">Pro:
    <select id="chosenpro" data-inline="true"></select>
    <button type="button" id="resetbutton" data-inline="true" data-theme="w">Reset</button>
</p>
```

I would like them to be displayed side by side (inline).
But I can't figure it out. I did [this](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/buttons/buttons-inline.html) but it doesn't work. Can you help ?
Here is my css:

```
#propart .ui-select {
    width:75%;
}
#propart .ui-select .ui-btn-icon-right {
    width:100%;
}
#propart .ui-btn {
    width:25%;
}
```

Comment: Use `<div class=ui-grid-a><div class=ui-block-a>button 1</div><div class=ui-block-b>button 2</div></div>`

Comment: thanks but what if I want that the first button has 75% width and the second a 25% width?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ui-grid` classes, and override their width.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/9DgNs/)**

Markup

```
<div class=ui-grid-a>
 <div class=ui-block-a>button 1</div>
 <div class=ui-block-b>button 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ui-block-a { width: 75% !important; }
.ui-block-b { width: 25% !important; }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to define any css rules.
jqm has [Layout grids](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.2/docs/content/content-grids.html)
All you need to do is:

```
<div class=ui-grid-a>
 <div class=ui-block-a> <select id="chosenpro" data-inline="true"></select></div>
 <div class=ui-block-b><button type="button" id="resetbutton" data-inline="true" data-theme="w">Reset</button></div>
</div>
```